# передать в func() значения view элемента в другой Controller

Tags: xcode, swift

Сначала начну с того что мне удалось, а в конце уже опишу проблему, так будет понятнее. В общем после Android Studio работа с view элементами в Xcode - та еще задача. Понимаю, что хороший программист не будет писать тот же код дважды, поэтому дабы каждый раз в разных Controller не описывать каждый раз view элементы - написал такую функцию в главном Controller, как это делают нормальные люди)

```
class func designForButton (button: UIButton){
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}
```

Затем к ней можно обращаться в разных Controller

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonBack: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ViewController.designForButton(button: buttonBack)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Вот теперь, то что не понятно. Я загрузил фреймворк для работы с Toast.И описал его значения в главном Controller

```
func designForToast(message: String){
    let style = CSToastStyle.init(defaultStyle: {
    }())
    _ = style?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    _ = style?.titleColor = UIColor.cyan
    _ = style?.messageColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.view.makeToast(message, duration: 2, position: self.bottomLayoutGuide, title: "title", image: UIImage (named: "logo.jpg"), style: style ) { (success: Bool) in
    }

}
```

Но дело в том, что в данном случае я могу к нему обратиться исключительно в этом же Controller

```
_=self.designForToast(message: "Its a Toast")
```

Как только я хочу сделать func() - как class func() для работы в другом Controller, мне Xcode начинает подсвечивать что это нельзя, и в силу своего малого опыта я своими силами не могу это исправить сам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы объяснить доступно и понятно, но я все же постараюсь, там где у тебя `self.view`, понимаешь `self` это ссылка на самого себя (на свой контроллер) если есть экран "А" грубо говоря и ты его описал как `ViewControllerA` то `self` это `ViewControllerA`, а `self.view` это вью `ViewControllerA`, через которое ты можешь брать размеры или как у тебя заюзать `toast`.
И так в чем проблема у тебя `class ViewController : UIViewcontroller` не содержит ссылки не активен, если можно так выразиться. Поэтому `self.view` ругается. Очень сложно объяснить литературным языком, советую прочитать про это. Если ты хочешь со всех разных классов  заюзать один метод `self.view` то советую попробовать в аргументе прописать еще что то типа

```
func designForToast(message: String, vc: UIViewController){
   vc.self.view.makeToast
}
```

что то типа этого.